# Sugeno, set output value 0 and 1, why sometimes the output value is 0.5

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I have set a Sugeno fuzzy controller to control the movement of a platte. When the value of output is 1, the platte moves, when the value is 0, the platte stops. But it's weird, sometimes the value is 0.5, I don't know what this represents and what's the stand of the platte at this moment. How can I improve that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the quickinfo of tag 'mathlab' is it mentioned, that you should add the info about the used version of mathlab.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly the reason why they are called fuzzy systems. They can produce outputs within the whole [0 1] range. You can check your rules for ambiguous combinations that might have lead to this result.